# truffle scripting

Tags: testing

i want to send a transaction every 10 seconds and observer it in truffle. In the course there is described how to send a single transaction, but is there a way to send it every 10 seconds with help of a javascript?

Something like:

```
Greetings.deployed().then(function(instance){app=instance;})

for( var i=0;i<10;i++){
    //wait for 10 seconds
    app.increaseCount();
}
```

But how can i implement the waiting function and how can i call the script from powershell?

Answer (score 1):

On test RPC just:

```
const delay = require("delay")

for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  await delay(10000).then(async () => {
      await instance.increaseCount({ from: account })
  })
  let i = await instance.i.call()
  console.log(new Date().getTime(), i.toNumber())
}
```

To do the same on the mainnet be sure to unlock your account before this loop with:

```
web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(account, password, time_period)
```

Comment: @Ismael sorry for that. The updated answer should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Roman's answer above,
to run an external script in truffle, use :

```
truffle exec name-of-your-file.js --network name-of-your-network
```

In windows, you may have to use `truffle.cmd`instead of `truffle`